# Como mudar a forma do botão com uma animação

Tags: android

Preciso fazer uma tela de login e no botão de login tenho que mudar o formato como o dessa imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de saber como é feito, obrigado desde já.

Comment: ao validar as informações após o click no botão(sign in) o botão fica como hide e na mesma proporção é trocado por uma imagem que muda seu formato para um circulo e em seguida carrega uma nova página com as informações do usuário. utilize JQuery + CSS3

Comment: Você podia tentar usar uma biblioteca, aqui tem listada algumas: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Button.md

Comment: Procure pesquisar sobre android **Fragment Transition Animation Material Design**, existem muitas bibliotecas que fazem esse efeito pra você.

Answer (score 7):

Como o [Leonardo Dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134066/como-mudar-a-forma-do-bot%c3%a3o-com-uma-anima%c3%a7%c3%a3o/153435#comment277911_134066) comentou. Isso é um  *Fragment Transition Animation Material Design*.
Parece complicado mas não é.

É apenas um botão que se transforma em uma `view` que cobre a tela toda.

Acho que em uma pesquisa básica de funcionamento do *Transition* você já vai entender e conseguir fazer.

---

Um exemplo simples:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.principal);
}

public void onButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaTela.class);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ActivityOptionsCompat compat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, button, "transtion_key");
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(this,intent, compat.toBundle());
}
}
```

---

SegundaTela.class

```
public class SegundaTela extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

---

Primeiro Layout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="transtion_key"
    android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="79dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

---

Segundo layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:transitionName="transtion_key"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Detalhe nos paramentos `android:transitionName="transtion_key"`, `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)` e no método `onButton(View view)`

Esse código faz a animação que a sua imagem mostra após o login ser feito (tela cheia).

Comment: O melhor jeito de salvar a resposta foi elaborar mais. +1